# Where to store CSV file for the schedule import CSv file data in salesforce

Tags: schedule

My requirement is I've to schedule the import of CSV file data into salesforce, on daily basis.

Means, Daily data from CSV file will be inserted into salesforce automatically.

Now. Question is third party will send me csv file daily, So where I can put that CSV file. SO it can be pickup from that place for the schedule import.

Where I can keep all csv file? what is the best place to store CSV.

I know the email drive and FTP server, but don't know if any other and which is best for further development

Answer (score 1):

You could leverage  [Data Loader Command Line](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/command_line_intro.htm) for scheduling import.

Refer [Step Four: Create the Configuration File](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/command_line_create_config_file.htm) where you need configure the network path to put your client supplied fields.

```
<entry key="dataAccess.name" value="X:\DLTest\In\insertAccounts.csv"/>
```

During import it will look for this path to find the files.

Comment: Question is: Where I can keep all csv file? Can you please read my question again.

Comment: Ftp server us preferable